# Docker volume mapping + windows = incredible slow?

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I am currently trying to copy data from my postgres, which runs within a docker-container, to my windows host. For this purpose I implemented a java application (also within a docker container) that uses the postgres-jdbc driver and its CopyManager in order to copy specific data to the host in mapped volume.

Problem: When I copy the data to the mapped windows directory, it becomes very slow. (Writing 1 GB of data takes about 40 minutes - without volume mapping only 1 minute)

Docker-compose:

```
  exportservice:
    build: ./services/exportservice
    volumes:
      - samplePath:/export_data
```

I have already read that it's a known problem, but I haven't found a suitable solution.
My services have to run in a production environment that is based on Windows.
So what's the way to solve this issue? WSL2?

Looking forward to your advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WSL2 instead of WSL and use the Linux file system. But you could also reduce your write cycles in order to reduce the writing overhead. This could be achieved by using a BufferedWriter in Java.

Answer (score 10):

Mounting a Windows folder into a Docker container is always slow no matter how you do it. WSL2 is even slower than WSL1 in that respect.

The best solution is to install WSL2, copy all your project files into the Linux file system (mounted in Windows at `\\wsl$\<distro>\`), run containers from there and mount Linux directories accordingly. That bypasses any Windows file interaction.

I wrote a **[Docker for Web Developers](https://dockerwebdev.com/)** book and video course because I couldn't find good getting-started tutorials which explained how to create local development environments. It includes Hyper-V and WSL2 instructions and advice. Use the discount code `dock30` for 30% off.

Comment: Thank you so much! Went from 31sec to 433ms for my API calls! I'm now able to develop again :-D

Comment: "That bypasses any Windows file interaction." -- at this point, I can just switch to Linux as I'm no longer able to use any Windows Tool while developing.